# How do I set up the calculation of tests(not steps) in the statistics of the report portal?

Tags: reportportal

I ran into a problem - I can not configure statistics for passing tests (not steps). All dashboards are built on the basis of counting the test steps.
Nowhere can I find information that will help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with current implementation. The only suggest in this case would be re-structuring test results you send to reportportal. 
As example, you can use [integration with Cucumber](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber). There are two reporters: ScenarioReporter and StepReporter. Step reporter sends each scenario step as separate test item. Scenario reporter aggregates information of all steps executed and then sends only one test item. 
ReportPortal accepts any structure: you can send suite-test-step as well as test-step or suite-test. Statistics in built based on lower tree level (for items that do not have children). So, for Cucumber's ScenarioReporter, the lowest item is scenario (not a step) and as result you can build statistics on top of Scenarios. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, since the original question, but since I ran into the same problem here's how I solved it:
I have a 3-tier solution: Launch-> Suite -> Step.
All my test cases are sent to ReportPortal as steps. I completely skip the "test" tag.
As a result, I get correct number of test cases in Dashboards and all the statistics for the failed tests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was experience same issue, where report portal was counting the steps instead of scenarios.

We are using gradle, cucumber and gitlab for the report portal configuration.

So, in the `cucumber.properties` we can configure the reporter plugin (as shown below)

```
cucumber.plugin=pretty,com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.ScenarioReporter
```

So, this will count the scenarios instead of steps.

If we want the steps to be counted then use

```
cucumber.plugin=pretty,com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.StepReporter
```